# How can I stop and rerun git clone command in case of a specified time delay?

Tags: command-line, ssh, git

I have a custom `clone` command. I call `clone org_name` and it automatically clones every repository of that organization for which the current developer has access to.

Of course my `clone` command uses GitHub API and then loops over the repos to create `git clone` commands.

However, sometimes the `git clone git@github.com:Org/Repo` hangs. And it fails with timeout error:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

This is related to either my Internet or the GitHub servers. But both of them are not in my hands and under my control.

I want to run the `git clone git@github.com:Org/Repo` and wait for like 3 seconds and in case it did not get an answer, I want to reissue this command.

Howe can I do that?

Comment: You could possibly use the `timeout` command in a loop - something like the answer here [Bash wait for a ping success](https://askubuntu.com/a/929711/178692)

Comment: Check the status (`$?`) of `git clone ...`, in a loop.